# Aumentar memoria para tabla virtuales en mysql

Tags: mysql, servidor

estoy realizando una inserción masiva a una tabla virtual en mysql
mi aplicación se cae por problemas en el servidor por lo que t
1: es el tiempo de conexion
2: memoria en el cache

es un servidor dedicado de 1 tera y 8 gb en ram por lo que quiero aumentar el rendimiento de mi BD por mas y mas que busco no logro en como cambiar la configuración pero si se que variable debo actualizar

Answer (score 0):

lo primero que debes hacer es ingresar en Phpmyadmin, si es tu caso y lo tienes instalado y te vas a la opcion de "Mostrar Infomracion de Tiempo de Ejecucion de MYSQL" y mostrar las variables del sistema, deberia estrar en el front principal.
algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
> wget mysqltuner.pl
> chmod 755 mysqltuner.pl
> perl mysqltuner.pl
```

Tambien puedes utilizar este script que recomiendan:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl

para ver los análisis de tu base de datos el cual te dara alguna sugerencias para que modifiques tu motor.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, pero tengo mi mysql en un linux, hay algun equivalente? saludos

Comment: casi todas las caracteristicas del motor de base de datos mysql se cambian en el archivo my.cnf, por lo general esta en /etc/my.cnf casi el 99% de todo esta alli.